# Настройка формы в Access 2007

Tags: access

Делаю простую БД в access. Имеется две таблички "Операция" и "ПО".

[image]

Для упрощения ввода данных создал форму "Form1", которая содержит вложенную форму "ПО02".

В данной форме я хочу сначала ввести значения в строках ""Откуда", "Куда", "Емкость", а потом просто вводить данные в "ИД_ПО".

Как сделать так, что бы при создание новой записи во вложенной форме "ПО02", строка "Операция" автоматом брала текущее(!) значения из строки "ID_Операции" формы "Form1".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В схеме базы данных установите связь между тпблицами
2. Создайте форму с подчиненной формой с помощью матсера
3. Допилите

Comment: Спасибо за совет.
Сегодня на свежую голову создал форму с помощью мастера, ничего допиливать не пришлось - все сразу заработало.